# Logic error with list loop

Tags: python

Once the user says "Yes" or "yes", the program is supposed to stop and display "Your favourite colour is" what ever colour they replied "yes" to.

If the user says "no" or "No", the program is supposed to loop until the user says "yes".

My problem is that it asks the user if the colour is the next one in the list without paying attention to if the user says yes!

```
import sys

colourList = ["Pink", "Orange", "Brown", "Black", "Green", "Yellow", "White", "Blue", "Red", "Grey"]
finished = False
i = 0

while not finished:
    for i in range (0,9):
        favColour=input("Is your favourite colour ?".format(colourList[i]))
        if favColour == ("Yes") or ("yes"):
            finished = True
        else:
            i = i + 1

print("Your favorite colour is {}.".format(colourList[i]))
```

Comment: More information is needed, what is the error you got? Paste the code from your terminal to the question, be more specific

Comment: which version of python is this ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the rules first. After you read them, provide your code, and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Put a [mcve] **in the question**. Code is text, posting a *picture* of your code is not that smart.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of your code with consideration of the IndexError that can appear after the list has run out of items:

```
  colorList = ['pink', 'blue', 'red']
  finished=False
  import sys

  i=0

  while not finished:
      for i in range(0, len(colorList)):
          favColour=input("Is your favourite color {}?:".format(colorList[i]))
        if favColour == "Yes" or favColour == "yes":
            print favColour
            finished = True
            print("Your favourite color is {}".format(colorList[i]))
            break
        else:
            i=i+1
```

- For Python 2.7 use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.
- We need to be more repetitive with this condition `if favColour == "Yes" or favColour == "yes":` (see answer below by minocha for another example)
- With `break` we are closing the program after correct result wanted. (Your flag `finished=True" can also be used, of course, if you have further code to execute after.)
- We are using the length of the list ( `len(colorList)` ) instead of a set number, as this will make the list start over after we've reached the last item/color.

Comment: Thanks, zondo. Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: While I would recommend that you wait for the user to provide their code as text, I think you can have an upvote for transcribing their image!

Comment: Much appreciated, halfer! I could also have added the code to his question, I see now :)

Comment: True, but make sure you avoid help vampires, who will soon discover your willingness to do their work for them `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

If its python2.7 input should be changed to raw_input

`favColour==("Yes")or("yes")` - is **not** the correct way to write the condition because this will always be true there are 2 assertions happening here favColour==("Yes") OR ("yes"). **Not favColour==("yes")**

An independent string is positive and would assert to true you should either change it to -

`favColour in ["yes", "Yes"]` 
OR
`favColour == "Yes" or favColour == "yes"`